# Azure Mobile Services linked tables

Tags: c#, azure, win-universal-app, azure-mobile-services

I have an application with 3 tables

```
Items, Clients, Types
```

Each item can be associated to one client and one type

This was originally stored using SQL Server CE and I have now pushed the data up to azure mobile services.

I am attempting to reuse this data in a new windows universal application written in c#.

In Azure I created 3 tables itemtable clienttable typetable, in itemtable I have columns for the id of the clienttable and typetable entry (item.clienttableid = clienttable.id).

The Azure mobile services backend is set to javascript, I chose this as I thought it would be more compatible across platforms than the .net backend is that true?

I want to be able to read all the items from the items table and reference the properties of the client and type table from the item (e.g. item.client.clientname)

Is there a way of defining my class so that when I request all items from azure I also get the associated type and client.

This is how I have my class so far

```
public class ItemTable
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "itemdate")]
    public DateTime ItemDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "itemamount")]
    public decimal ItemAmount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "itemdescription")]
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ItemClientID")]
    public ClientTable Client { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ItemTypeID")]
    public TypeTable Type { get; set; }
}

public class ClientTable
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientname")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
}

public class TypeTable
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "typename")]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

I have seen this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/08/23/complex-types-and-azure-mobile-services.aspx
but cannot wrap my head around how to adapt it to my situation

Answer (score 1):

> The Azure mobile services backend is set to javascript, I chose this as I thought it would be more compatible across platforms than the .net backend is that true?

No matter which time of backend you are using, it will be easy in each case because Azure Mobile Services Team created a "[Azure Mobile Services SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices/)" for client applications, which you can install by "Manage Nuget Package".

> This is how I have my class so far

I saw the model and next time you can show the class diagram from your model, learn about in this article [Class diagram: a easy way to understand code](http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/class-diagram-a-easy-way-to-understand-code/). If this model is for the client/.Net Backend, I think it is not completely correct because you said this

> 3 tables Items, Clients and Types. Each item can be associated to one client and one type

In the ItemTable class you need to have something like it

```html
             public ClientTable ClientId { get; set; }
 
       [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ItemClientID")]
       public virtual ClientTable Client { get; set; }
  
    public string TypeTableId { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("TypeTableId")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ItemTypeID")]
       public virtual TypeTable TypeTable { get; set; }
```

**Note**: In client apps remove the attribute ForeignKey.

If you have doubts I recommend to see this

[Azure Mobile Services Samples - Samples and articles to help developers to use Azure Mobile Services](https://github.com/saramgsilva/AzureMobileServices)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have data in the tables in azure mobile services presently and have set itemclientid and itemtypeid to be the same as the id field in each respective table. I am trying to now consume this data and map it to the appropriate client or type. I guess my question really is do I pull this from azure as a view or do I pull the 3 tables individually and create the view on the client by matching the IDs. I hope this makes sense.